# Quarkus Redis client not using host from application.properties

Tags: java, redis, quarkus

Using Quarkus 1.12.2Final, the Redis client is not using the config properties I set for it in application.properties

application.properties content:

```
%dev.quarkus.redis.hosts=redis://redis_dev:6379
%prod.quarkus.redis.hosts=redis://redis_prod:6379
```

Neither host exists so I should get a connection failure. I wrap the Redis client in another class that prints the config:

```
import io.quarkus.redis.client.RedisClient;
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class RedisClientWrapper {
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RedisClientWrapper.class);
    
        public RedisClientWrapper() {
        }
    
        @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.redis.hosts")
        String redisHost;
    
        @Inject
        RedisClient redisClient;
    
        @PostConstruct
        void init(){
                LOG.info("Redis client initialized. Configured host: "+redisHost);
        }
```

When running the app, this is the output:

```
2021-03-25 18:46:47,517 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2021-03-25 18:47:02,609 INFO  [RedisClientWrapper] (executor-thread-1) Redis client initialized. Configured host: redis://redis_dev:6379
```

The app however connects to my redis running on localhost, and everything works.

By running it as a JAR,

```
./mvnw package
java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar
```

I run it with the prod profile

```
2021-03-25 18:50:26,620 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated. 
2021-03-25 18:50:37,555 INFO  [RedisClientWrapper] (executor-thread-1) Redis client initialized. Configured host: redis://redis_prod:6379
```

Still same behaviour, the Redis client connects to localhost.

Why does the Redis client not use the host name specified in the config?

UPDATE: The issue is most likely due to the underscores in my hostname, and the fact that the Quarkus Redis client internally uses java.net.URI for the hostnames, which does not accept underscores. I've opened a bug for it on [GitHub](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/16037)

Comment: Can you try with no profile to see if it works ?

Comment: It seems like a Quarkus bug/issue, updated the main post.